# nginx reverse proxy images and css are not loaded

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I try to configure an nginx reverse proxy to access a Jenkins instance. I can open the authentication page but there is no CSS and no image. It works perfectly when direct access.

All works as if the reverse proxy does not rewrite correctly URLs defined in the html source page. Have I missed something ?

Here is my nginx configuration :

```
    location /jenkins {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect false;
            proxy_pass http://jenkins:8080/;
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

I found the solution. The nginx reverse proxy works well but Jenkins need some customization to work with reverse proxy.

The final nginx configuration :

```
location /jenkins/ {
    proxy_pass http://jenkins:8080/jenkins/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

And [the tutorial](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+behind+an+NGinX+reverse+proxy) to configure jenkins behind nginx reverse proxy which solved my problem

Comment: Glad this worked for you. Feel free to click the green checkbox and [mark this answer as 'Accepted'](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) to let everyone else know the problem has been solved :)

Comment: This helped me, but I am [running it behind Apache](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+Apache).  Particularly the part about "make sure you add a slash at the end of all URLs in proxy params in apache".

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if above statement worked for OP but I know that altering location name line did the trick for me:

```
  location ^~ /jenkins/ {
    proxy_pass http://jenkins:8080/jenkins/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Jenkins with docker. You can add the environment part of compose file as below:

```yaml
environment:
 JENKINS_OPTS: "--prefix=/jenkins"
```

in the nginx conf file. proxy_pass must refer to the `http://IP-ADDRESS:PORT/jenkins/`. As mentioned before, the [link](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+behind+an+NGinX+reverse+proxy) as a reference is very usefull.